# Bootstrap text next to image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i am before a problem which probably all of you met before. I need to place text next to image, in my case everything is done inside the MODAL window.

I found multiple ways how to do it in bootstrap, unfortunately it doesn't work for me, prolly I miss something really simple so i hope someone can advise me what I'm doing wrong.

This is my code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">PŘIPRAVUJEME</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="http://tpot.cz/Images/cv/antikody-small.png" class="pull-left">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                      <p>Václav Havel ANTIKÓDY
                  V prodeji ve dvou variantách v limitovaném luxusním provedení v kovových deskách Promolyte nebo
                  v papírových deskách Fedrigoni s koženým hřbetem
                  Rezervace jsou možné na emailové adrese info@tpot.cz
                  K prodeji od 1. 10. 2015</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use `media` component which comes with Bootstrap. Simply put inside `modal-body` element. Example:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="media">
    <div class="media-left">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://tpot.cz/Images/cv/antikody-small.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <p>Václav Havel ANTIKÓDY V prodeji ve dvou variantách v limitovaném luxusním provedení v kovových deskách Promolyte nebo v papírových deskách Fedrigoni s koženým hřbetem Rezervace jsou možné na emailové adrese info@tpot.cz K prodeji od 1. 10. 2015</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey  @neilhem I just try this and it still display me text below the image.
Screen avaliable: http://www.upnito.sk/0/ywhxjev3zfp757me64mbts59wf8z5cvs.png

Comment: align them inline-block?

Comment: @Andurit Seems like you do not have styles of media component, double check if media component's styles included. I also assume that you use Bootstrap 3 based on grid classes you used in example in your question.